# Subversion tells me a folder is up to date, when it isn't

Tags: svn

So I've been working with subversion (and IntelliJ) for almost a year now. Every once in a while, subversion seems to get corrupted or something, and it won't update properly. After updating, i'll find files in the repo-browser that won't get checked out into my file system. Updating again says all files are up to date.

I've fixed this for myself once in the past by deleting my entire source and re-checking it all out.

This happens to me and the other two devs on my team. Anyone know what could be wrong?

--edit--

Using tortoise svn and intelliJ concurrently for subversion on a windows xp machine.

Comment: How do you check whether a folder is up-to-date? What SVN client are you using? What platform? What software is used for your SVN server?

Comment: Most svn problems I've seen stem from global replaces / edits in files in the _entire_ tree of a project, which includes the `.svn` directory which should be left alone. However, I cannot quite imagine how it would result in your described problems. Do you per chance have a `svn -v stat` output from the moment of trouble?

Comment: sorry, don't have an svn -v stat

Comment: I usually update from IntelliJ, but I'll also update through tortoise svn's shell integration update command.

Comment: Is the problem that the icon overlay in Windows Explorer is incorrect? Or does calling the *SVN Update* command from the TortoiseSVN context menu not update your repository?

Comment: Calling the 'SVN Update' command from the context menu doesn't update my repository. For some reason, it isn't pulling the updates (it "thinks" its already up to date)